# Create Multiple Outlook Tasks from list in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I wrote code to loop through a list in Excel, creating a task in Outlook for each line item.

While I can loop through each, only one task is being saved.

I receive an error

> "This reminder will not appear because the item is in a folder that doesn't support reminders. Is this OK?"

It works if I only have one task.

```
Public Sub Create_Task()

    Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim OutTask As Outlook.TaskItem

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutTask = OutApp.CreateItem(olTaskItem)

    Dim i As Integer
    i = 1

    Do While Not IsEmpty(Range("Task").Offset(i, 0))

        With OutTask
            .Subject = Range("Project_Name") & " - " & Range("Task").Offset(i, 0)
            .StartDate = Range("Start_Date").Offset(i, 0)
            .DueDate = Range("Due_Date").Offset(i, 0)
            .ReminderSet = True
            .ReminderTime = Range("Reminder_Time").Offset(i, 0)
            .Body = Range("Body").Offset(i, 0)
            .Save
        End With

        i = i + 1
        Loop

    Set OutTask = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

I expect as many tasks as Excel line items in my task list. I can see each task being generated but overwritten.

Comment: Move the line `Set OutTask = OutApp.CreateItem(olTaskItem)` inside the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try:**

```
Public Sub Create_Task()

Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OutTask As Outlook.TaskItem

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Dim i As Integer
i = 1

Do While Not IsEmpty(Range("Task").Offset(i, 0))

Set OutTask = OutApp.CreateItem(olTaskItem)
    With OutTask
        .Subject = Range("Project_Name") & " - " & Range("Task").Offset(i, 0)
        .StartDate = Range("Start_Date").Offset(i, 0)
        .DueDate = Range("Due_Date").Offset(i, 0)
        .ReminderSet = True
        .ReminderTime = Range("Reminder_Time").Offset(i, 0)
        .Body = Range("Body").Offset(i, 0)
        .Save
    End With
Set OutTask = Nothing

    i = i + 1
    Loop

Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```